Eslint Custom Processors Post-Process Auto-Fix adjust re-linting 10 times
im making eslint Custom Processor plugin for Qml's js, everything working okay, im trying to add support for auto-fixing starting with semicolons auto fix, i have to adjust the character offset to match the original place in the original file, which i do correctly and the auto-fix does place the missing semi colon BUT it re-lint 10 times and places 10 semicolons at the same place
before auto-fix:
bautofix
After auto-fix:
aautofix
my code:
    function postprocess(messages, filename) {
        const blocks = blocksCache.get(filename);
        blocksCache.delete(filename);
        // console.log("Postprocessing Output:", messages, filename);
    
    
        return messages.flatMap((group, i) => {
            console.log(i, group)
            if (Array.isArray(group) && group.length === 0) {
                return [];
            }
    
    
            return group.map((err) => {
                
                const block = blocks[i];
                if (block.type == 'var' && err.ruleId === 'semi'){
                    err.ruleId = 'semi-var'
                }
                const adjustedError = {
                    ...err,
                    line: (err.line || 0) + (blocks[i]?.location.start.line - 1 || 0),
                };
                if (err.fix && block) {
                    console.log(adjustedError, err.fix.range || 0);
                    // console.log(blocks[i]?.code + ';ll', blocks[i]?.code[err.fix.range[0]]);
                    adjustedError.fix.range = [
                        err.fix.range[0] + block.location.start.offset,
                        err.fix.range[1] + block.location.start.offset,
                        
                    ]
                    console.log(adjustedError.line, adjustedError.fix.range, err.column, block.location.start.offset);
                    console.log(blocks[i]?.code);
    
    
                }
                return adjustedError;
            }).filter(excludeUnsatisfiableRules);
        });
    }

Can you spot any bugs? is there something i missed in the docs? is it possible that eslint re-lint old version of the file before the auto-fix was applied as kind of auto-fix validation?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
